# not_actions vs explicit deny & allow statements in an IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies

Policy 1:

```json
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "AllowEKSKMSAccess"
    actions = [
      "kms:*"
    ]
    not_actions = [
      "kms:Delete*",
      "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
      "kms:Revoke*",
      "kms:Disable*",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

Policy 2:

```json
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "AllowEKSKMSAccess"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "kms:*"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid = "DenyEKSKMSDeletion"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "kms:Delete*",
      "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
      "kms:Revoke*",
      "kms:Disable*",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

I want to prevent 4 actions from within the role associated with a managed EKS node group.

Is policy 1 or policy 2 the preferred policy?

Is it better to have explicit `deny` statements (along with `allow` statements) in the same policy?

Comment: The former policy will not prevent accidental privilege escalation if a 2nd policy is added to that user/group/role and it permits the undesirable KMS actions. The latter policy will prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is policy 1 or policy 2 the preferred policy?

Policy 2.

> Is it better to have explicit `deny` statements (along with `allow` statements) in the same policy?

Yes - if you want to deny any IAM actions, **always** prefer explicit deny policies.

[An explicit deny in any policy overrides any allows.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow)

As long as the original deny policy is protected from changes, any new policies added that attempt to allow the unwanted actions *will not work*.

However, when using `not_actions` with the allow effect, any new policies added to allow the unwanted actions will actually reverse the effect of the original policy & *will allow the undesired actions*. With no explicit deny, there is nothing stopping someone else from adding an explicit allow (most of the time).

The 2nd policy is always preferred.

I only use `not_actions` when I want to *deny* a lot of things to make the resulting IAM policy smaller, as I know it is guaranteed to be future proof if the policy is well-secured.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and for the answer as well!

Comment: Thanks for editing my question and for the answer as well!

Comment: @DmitrySemenov No worries, enjoy using AWS :)

Answer (score 0):

None, create IAM Policies:

- with `Allow` effect where you have the list of **precise** `Action`s, because you can always allow more than you should with wildcard `*`, don't be lazy especially when you have AWS tools like [IAM Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com)
- with explicit ARNs for `Resource`s (at least precise the account), **avoid `[*]`**

Since you are using Terraform, you have tools like [Checkov](https://www.checkov.io/1.Welcome/Quick%20Start.html) for analyzing your code and giving you best practice tips.